# Shortcut for creating constructor with base (C# Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio C# you can, in a class, type `ctor` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and Visual Studio will create a constructor for that class for me. Very convenient.

But is there a way (shortcut) to make Visual Studio generate all constructors with bases from its inherited class?

For example,

```
public class User:ClassA
{
    public User() {}
    public User(string S):base(S) {}
    public User(string S, int I):base(S, I) {}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not have ReSharper and it is possible.

You can select your base class and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and select *Generate All*:

[image]

I am not sure if it comes with the Visual Studio 2015 installation; maybe you need to add an extension. I am not sure which one of them it is required.

Following the extensions I have installed that maybe good candidates:

- Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
- PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2015
- Productivity Power Tools 2015
- Snippet Designer
- Visual Studio Extensibility Templates

Comment: Do you have to add some extension or it comes directly from VS2015?

Comment: No! Just a clean installation! :)